# Angular 9: Observable Getter Returning Object Instead of Boolean from BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, observable, getter, angular9, behaviorsubject

My apologies if this is posted somewhere on Stack Overflow, but I'm not finding a answer that works for me.

I have a BehaviorSubject that tracks a state as a boolean value. I also have a public getter method that is an Observable that returns the BehaviorSubject. I do this so that not only can I subscribe to changes in the BehaviorSubject value, but to also get the current value when it hasn't changed. While I'm able to get the proper value from subscribe, I am getting an Object returned when just calling the getter. I want it to return the last value.

I've tried using .getValue(), which does not seem to work, and I've tried .value, which does seem to work but throws an error in the IDE.

I've created a very basic example of what I'm trying to accomplish and I've put comments in the my.service.ts file to show what I'm going for. Please advise. Thank you!

EDIT: I used what was in stack blitz by default and assigned the getter to the name variable just to see it. My goal is to get the value so that I can do something based on wether the value is true or false. I'm sure I'm missing something really simple.

EDIT: Adding code to question as requested

EDIT: I've also added the .subscribe to show that while I understand that's how Observables work, I also want to check the value OUTSIDE of a value change using the same getter if it is possible.

**MyService**

```
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";

export class MyService {

  constructor() {}

  private _isBoolean = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  public get isBoolean(): Observable<boolean> {
    //return this._isBoolean.value; // Returns boolean, but throws error "Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>'."
    return this._isBoolean; // Returns object, but I want the value
  }

}
```

**AppComponent**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from './my.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name;

  constructor(private _myservice: MyService) {
    this._myservice.isBoolean.subscribe(val => {
      console.log("value from subscribe: " + val)
    })

    this.name = this._myservice.isBoolean;
    if (this._myservice.isBoolean) {
      console.log("true!");
    } else if (!this._myservice.isBoolean) {
      console.log("false!");
    }
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hhdgrc

Comment: You should put your code in your answer

Comment: For this, it is needed to define new value like (subjectBoolean).
And whenever emit the value to BehaviorSubject, set that subjectBoolean value together and on getter method, returns that subjectBoolean.

Comment: @Derek.W Can you give a coded example? I'm not following what you're saying. Thank you.

Comment: or you can get the value like this: `this._isBoolean.getValue()` on MyService, then it will work.

Comment: @Derek.W Two things happen when I attempt that: One is that I get an error about assigning booleans to an Observable<boolean> and Two,  get an error that says "subscribe is not a function"

Comment: check my updated answer. I have updated your `app.component.ts` code to work for you.

Comment: You can use BehaviorSubject directly, no need to use observable.
So it's good t make BehaviorSubject variable as public and on getIsBoolean return the rela boolean value only using `BehaviorSubject.getValue()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks goes out to Rahmat Ali for leading me to the answer I needed. I'm providing an answer here to make it easier to find, provide a simpler example of the solution, and a better explanation.

I wanted to have a getter function that allowed me to both subscribe to changes to the value of a BehaviorSubject and also be able to get the current value without a subscription depending on the current need.

The reason it wasn't working is that in following another example, I made the getter return an Observable type rather than a BehaviorSubject type. So, I was getting a "truthy" result in the console because I was checking for the existence of it rather than the boolean value. Once that changed, I was able to access the boolean value of the BehaviorSubject with the .value property.

Here is a simplified example of the solution (NOTE: the getter was unnecessary because once the getter returned the BehaviorSubject, I could change its value using .next without creating a setter):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  private _isBooleanSubejct = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  public get isBoolean(): BehaviorSubject<boolean> {
    return this._isBooleanSubejct;
  }

  constructor() {
    console.log(this.isBoolean.value);
    this.isBoolean.subscribe(val => {
      console.log(val); // false until the timer completed
      console.log(this.isBoolean.value); // false until the timer completed
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.isBoolean.next(true);
    }, 5000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using `Observables` in wrong way. Please add a `subscribe` call to the `observable`:

```
this._myservice.isBoolean.subscribe((val) => {
    this.name = val;
    console.log("value: " + val);
});
```

---

You can just add code in `subscribe` callback to use the changing value:

**Edited `app.component.ts`**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from './my.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name;

  constructor(private _myservice: MyService) {
    this._myservice.isBoolean.subscribe(val => {
      console.log("value from subscribe: " + val);


      this.name = val ;
      if (val) {
        console.log("true!");
      } else if (!val) {
        console.log("false!");
      }
    })

  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Rahmat. While I am using subscribe in some areas of my code (not shown in the example because the error does not exist there), I'm trying to also use the getter to get the current value, not just when the value changes. Is the issue that I cannot have an Observable getter when trying to just get the current value of the BehaviorObject?

Comment: `BehaviorSubject` is used to get the initial value when we `subscribe` to it. So, the time we apply `subscribe` call to `BehaviorSubject`, `subscribe` function will have current value. You should not have to use `getter` here as it is not required. Please check updated stackbliz to clearify the usage of `BehaviorSubject`: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9bgcqw)

Comment: The purpose of the BehaviorSubject is that the value may be changed by another method later on and I want to be able to react to those changes through the subscribe method. I did not put anything in the example code to change it after initialization because that was not the part I'm struggling with. I want to be able to see the current value without having to subscribe to the getter. Otherwise every time the value changes, there will be yet another method that handled value changes. Am I making sense? It's starting to sound like a need another getter that is not Observable.

Comment: You can use `.value` getter to get the current value. Use it on `BehaviorSubject` anytime and you will have current value. But you are calling a function from your service, which is returning `Observable` (`isBoolean(): Observable<boolean>`), if you update return type to `BehaviorSubject<boolean>` or to `any`, it will work for you also on callback.

Comment: @AncientSpice I have updated the stackblits. Added some examples. Check it: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dbcfwf)

Comment: Thank you, @Rahmat! That was what I was looking for!

Comment: @AncientSpice, also you can use the `pipe` and add `take(1)` as @abhay tripathi suggested, if you do not want to update the return type of the function from `Observable` to another.

Answer (score 1):

**Correct way** to use *Boolean BehaviorSubject* :-

define like this:-

```
_isBoolean: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
```

update like this :-

```
this._isBoolean.next(true); //  for true
this._isBoolean.next(false); // for false
```

read value in some other component : -

```
this._isBoolean.subscribe(value => {
console.log(value);
    });
```

read current value immediately only one time :-

```
this._isBoolean.asObservable().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(value => {
    console.log(value);
  });
```

Comment: what do you mean by outside of a value change ?

Comment: even when the value don't change automitically, you still want to get the value. Am I right ? for this also you have to subscribe to it and it will immediately give value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the html part of the app the service returns an observable for which the template has to subscribe. For this purpose you have to add async pipe to the template variable

Add the async pipe to the app component.html variable. This will do the trick

```
<hello name="{{ name|async }}"></hello>
```

Comment: While I appreciate the feedback, I'm afraid it misses the point of my question. It's not that I can't see the value in HTML. It's that the getter is returning an Object and not a boolean. This happens even if I just write a call to the getter in the console. Sorry I was not more clear.

Comment: returning any time the value of an observable happens in the subcription. If you want some logic based on the vbalue of the isBoolean then you have to subsribe to the observable in the service as well